# Send Transactional Mail using mailchimp

Tags: laravel, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am developing web application using Laravel. In this application I have to send email to the user. Now I want to send those emails using MailChimp. Can anyone guide me how can I send one to one email using MailChimp in Laravel.

I am using below code to send email please check and let me know what to do to send email

```
$apikey = '<key>-us12';
    $to_emails = array('test@gmail.com');
    $to_names = array('test');
    $message = array(
        'html' => 'Yo, this is the <b>html</b> portion',
        'text' => 'Yo, this is the *text* portion',
        'subject' => 'This is the subject',
        'from_name' => 'OMO CRM',
        'from_email' => 'customerservice@test.com',
        'to_email' => $to_emails,
        'to_name' => $to_names
    );
    $tags = array('WelcomeEmail');
    $params = array(
        'apikey' => $apikey,
        'message' => $message,
        'track_opens' => true,
        'track_clicks' => false,
        'tags' => $tags
    );
    $url = "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?' . http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($result);
    echo "Status = " . $data->status . "\n";
```

I am not able to send email using above code.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could send transactional mail through Mailchimp's API. Mailchimp provide a transactional mail service, called [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) which might be what you're looking for. Could you provide information to the documentation that you're using as a guide to using the API for sending transactional mail? It looks to me like you're not specifying an end point to their API.